# iframe in Firefox not resizing on magnification

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript `document.body.offsetWidth` to get the width and using that to calculate the `frame.style.left`.

I am using the `<body onresize='func()'>` event. everything works fine. In Firefox and chrome. But when in android tab, i double tap to magnify the iframe in Firefox, Firefox will magnify the page and the iframe goes off into the side and even if i move the page left/right, it still maintains the `frame.style.left` set by the script.

This is happening only in Firefox. Chrome seems to work fine.

My question is how do I correct this.

I can do a CSS work around, but how would I do it in javascript.

Regards and thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question! Made me think. Well, searching on the web I found a solution. Basically you will be looking for text size change.

How you would do this is, have a hidden `span`, register the `height`, add an `event listener` and check in intervals if the height has changed. If the height changes, it means the page was zoomed.

At a look at the tutorial. [link to article.](http://alistapart.com/article/fontresizing)

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! thanks! magnification~zoom